# Automatically closing "popover" on success

Tags: javascript

I have created a "popover" which contains a form. When this form is submitted, the form values are being sent to a server using Ajax.

The server will respond with messages like

> not successful, try again

or

> all successful

I would like to close the "popover" whenever the server responds with success. If the form was not successfully submitted, the "popover" should linger and possibly display a error message.

Comment: why voted this question down

Comment: I didn't vote it down myself but I think they probably thought the question was difficult to read or understand

Comment: I voted it down because you have 1) displayed no research effort. Where is your code? 2) It is important that the answer can be _read_. Correct your grammatical and syntactical errors! 3) What is being asked? Where is the question?

Comment: any ways keep discouraging the young programmers ,well done,keep going

Comment: Maybe it was for the best. In the real world, e.g. in a job, not being able to write properly is a huge drawback. But why not address my concerns? Add code, fix your spelling and clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

instead of popover, have you consider about using a modal object from [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)?
You will have a better control of the object, and it is prettier.

just put the action button of the form in your modal, and upon success, you can hide the modal using jQuery call.